# Wonder if volume slider(from physical keyboard) value can be retrieved only when it's finished changing

Tags: autohotkey, volume

Like I said, normally value from physical keyboard volume slider changes with every modification in its range(0 - 100 usually)

But, I'd like to utilize this volume slider value into somewhat differently. Say, I want to retrieve the volume value 33 and save it into variable and trigger some command with that. This way, I can't properly achieve what I aimed for as the commands will be made every milliseconds if I make a multiple number of volume change.

I had a look if somebody had ever questioned and got an answer but couldn't find one. Hope I can get any help or tip. Thanks

Comment: Can you add a link to such a keyboard with a volume slider like this so that we can get a better idea of what you are talking about?

Comment: https://photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Palette-Gear-Expert-Kit-Review-3-1536x1025.jpg  Didn't know how to introduce this as, so I called it as physical keyboard. And that might have made you confused. The one I asked for is this slider key. You move it towards up and down, and volume is up and down. Hope I clarified

Comment: this might need some special work if you specific devices, but if it's just volume, look at this: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundGet.htm

Comment: Thanks for sharing the tip. I looked at it, and probably I might be able to get what I want from here, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

I think a two part script would work:

1. Save the volume value in variable when the hot key triggers
2. Have a label that is running every x seconds and checking the
   variable

For example:

```
test := 0
; Label setup
volumeLabel:
MsgBox, Test was %test%
return

!z::
test := A_Sec
return
```

If your volume slider can't trigger a hotkey, just start the [label](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Labels.htm) when the script starts, then keep it running forever and have it check the volume with [SoundGet](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundGet.htm).